# Landscape splitview like jamie oliver app in xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4, ipad

I am new at xcode and i want to build an ipad app that will look like the jamie oliver version. I tried many approaches even using the root/detailviewcontroller approach, but it is not the result what i want to see.

What i want is that the rootviewcontroller will show at the bottom of the screen and the detailviewcontroller above it in Landscape mode. Like the jamie app.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/), but it looks like it's no longer in active development.  You may run into a couple issues, but it's open source so you can modify it if you need to.